# Does this proof of the binomial expansion (a+b)^2 work?

Tags: solution-verification, peano-axioms

I was rereading Terence Tao's Analysis 1 and found this question in the section:

> Exercise $2.3.4.$ Prove the identity $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ for all natural
> numbers a, b.

Prior to this we already have proved:

$1.a\cdot b=b\cdot a\\2.a\cdot b=0\implies a=0\lor b=0\\3.a\cdot (b\cdot c)=(a\cdot b)\cdot c\\4. a\cdot (b+c)=a\cdot b+a\cdot c\\$

So I wrote this down:

$(x+y)^2\\=(x+y)(x+y)\\=x(x+y)+y(x+y)\\=x^2+xy+xy+y^2\\=x^2+2xy+y^2$

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: It's important for this type of exercise to label what theorem / result you're using for each step, because most people reading this won't know if you've had that in your head or not. I'd go back and label each line with which of 1,2,3,4 you're using. Then it'll be clear if it's correct or not.

Comment: Thanks, I did think about doing that. I'll keep that in mind next time

Comment: Properties 2 and 3 are certainly not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the modified version of your proof with few skipped steps added and properties mentioned.

\begin{align}
(x+y)^2 &=(x+y).(x+y) & \\
&=(x(x+y))+(y(x+y))&\text{(using property 4 and 1)} \\
&=(x.x +x.y )+(y.x +y.y) &\text{(using property 4 again)}\\&=x^2+(x.y+y.x)+y^2 &\text{(using associativity of addition)}\\ &=x^2+(x.y+x.y)+y^2 &\text{(since $y.x=x.y$, property 1)}\\&=x^2+(1.xy+1.xy)+ y^2 &\text{(using property: $1.a=a$ for all natural numbers $a$)} \\
&=x^2 + (1+1). xy + y^2 &\text{(using property 4)}\\ 
&=x^2+2xy+y^2 &\text{(using 1+1=2)}\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Basically correct, but here are two remarks:

- From $(x + y)(x + y)$ to $x(x + y) + y(x + y)$ you need the result $(a + b)\cdot c = a \cdot c + b \cdot c$ which can be proved from 1. 4. but you haven't done it.
- From $x(x + y) + y(x + y)$ you can only get $(x^2 + xy) + (yx + y^2)$. In order to be able to write it as $x^2 + xy + xy + y^2$, you need to know that $+$ is associative, namely $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$, so that order of addition doesn't matter.

Comment: At this stage of the book, Tao takes facts about addition and order for granted with no further explanation, which might be why OP didn’t mention the fact that addition is associative.